# Mongoose CastError

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following code, which does absolutely nothing, and for some reasons, I have an error with mongoose which is not even called, here's the code:

```
.post('/testRequest', express.json(), upload.none(), async (req, res) => {
    try {
      res.status(200);
      res.send('test');
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.stack);
      res.status(err.code || 400);
      res.send(err.message || err);
    }
  })
```

And here's the error:

```
message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "test" at path "_id" for model "Requests"',
name: 'CastError',
stringValue: '"test"',
kind: 'ObjectId',
value: 'test',
path: '_id',
reason: undefined,
```

I've tried many things but didn't seem to fix it

Comment: you can refer to this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34985332/express-mongoose-router-cast-to-objectid-failed-for-value-undefined-at-path

Comment: Do you have a .post(':id', ...) on top of this code? What route you are sending the request to receive this error? Is it /test ?

Comment: have you used _id with type ObjectId and assigning it "test" string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a `.post(':id', ...)` on top of your code. So a post request to `/testRequest` matches the `'/:id'` and `'/testRequest'` routes, but only the top one executes.
The `':id'` route reads `testRequest` as an ID and throws the CastError.

You can swap the order of the methods, which was already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49700471/casterror-cast-to-objectid-failed-for-value-route-name-at-path-id-for-mode).